# CodeIgniter send multiple email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using CodeIgniter with its default library. And whenever I send an email, it's sending it twice. Does anyone have some debugging pointers or hints to resolve this issue?

```
$this->CI->email->from($this->from, $this->company_name);
$this->CI->email->to($this->to);
$this->CI->email->subject($this->subject);

eval("\$message = \"".$this->message."\";");

$this->CI->email->message($this->message);

if($attachment != "")
{
    $attac_exp=explode(",",$attachment);

    foreach($attac_exp as $key=>$value) 
    {
        if($value != '')
        {
            $this->CI->email->attach(getcwd()."/attachments/".$value);                 
        }
    }
}

$this->CI->email->send();
$this->CI->email->clear(true);
```

I have configured sendmail with SMTP for now.

If I try to send an email via the command line I am getting only one email. As far as I know, the issue must be with CodeIgniter. I have already done my research on this.

Comment: I had a similar problem in phalcon frame, for the body of my message, i had to implicate ob_start(), and ob_clean and clear message...

There is something similar in codeigniter: send([$auto_clear = TRUE]), maybe it would help

Comment: Thanks Denis, For reply yeah i see that and i already put that in my code but still somehow it was not working for me

Comment: show your controller code or model code where you send this mail, because i think you are calling this function twice ...

Comment: That i also double check before post here there is no multiple time calling this function

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample snippet that works perfectly with attaching a single file in the email. Please refer and rectify accordingly.

```
        $config = array();
        $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
        $config['mailpath'] = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "localhost";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $dummyfrom='admin@mydoamin.com';
        $system_name  = "Test Company";
        $from = 'rajesh@abcd.com';
        $to ='to@abcd.com';
        $bcc = 'bcc@abcd.com';$sub="Attachment Test";
        $msg = "Please ignore this mail";
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from($dummyfrom, $system_name);
        $this->email->reply_to($from);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->bcc($bcc);
        $this->email->subject($sub);
        $this->email->message($msg);
        $this->email->attach(APPPATH.'test.txt');
        $this->email->send();
```

Note that it picks the file `test.txt` from the app path.
You can use `$this->email->print_debugger()` to see the debug.

Comment: Ankit, is this same code also sending it twice? you can apply it in a different function and check. With this you are sure its not codeigniter that sends twice, but the program logic somewhere is wrong.